# creating Typoscript dropdown menu

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a problem with creating a menu with typoscript.
This is how the menu should look in html

```
<div class="dropdown-menu hidden-xs" role="menu">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <header>
          <a href="#">Item lvl2</a>
        </header>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Item lvl3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I have never worked with Typoscript. 
Can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: If you have never worked with it maybe the docs are a good place to start? http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/

Comment: also a search on the internet might reveal answers http://typo3buddy.com/typoscript/menus/tmenu-left-menu/

Comment: Thanks, I have readen this. But I cant make it working(

Comment: What's the problem with that?

Comment: @PavelPirog, please note that StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. If you've already gotten started with TypoScript, please include the code you're having problems with in your question.